# JQuery script to total values from input boxes, checkboxes and option values from select element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to write what I think must be a simple JQuery script to display a running sum total of options selected by a user in an order form.  I have assigned values to all the checkboxes, radio buttons and option values from my drop downs and now want to display the sum total in a div so a user can see the total.

Here is my pathetic first attempt.  It doesn't work and I'm not surprised... just can't quite get my around why.

[image: Image of input form]

Here is the updated form code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var baseWarranty = $("input.basewarranty").val();
    var multiFlat = $("option.multiflat").toarray[];
    var multiyr = $("option.multiyr").toarray[];
    var newConst = $("option.newconst").toarray[];
    var warrantyOptions = $("input.warrantyoptions").toarray[];
    var optionsChecked = $(baseWarranty: selected, multiFlat: selected, multiyr: selected, newConst: selected, warrantyOptions: checked).val();
    $(baseWarranty, multiFlat, multiyr, newConst, warrantyOptions).change(function() {
      if (optionsChecked) {
        $("#wty_option_child2").append(optionsChecked);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="centercolumntd">
      <label for="closingdate"><u>Closing Date</u></label><br>
      <input type="date" id="closingdate" name="closingdate" required><br><br>
      <label for="hometype"><u>Type of Home</u></label><br><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Single Family" name="hometype" value="singlefamily" required><label for="Single Family">Single Family</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home" name="hometype" value="towncondomobile"><label for="Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home">Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home</label><br>
      <select form="input_form" name="multitype" id="duplex_triplex_fourplex" value="Multi-Flat Warranty Options" class="selectboxes">
        <option class="multiflat" value="" selected disabled hidden>Duplex/Triplex/Fourplex</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="duplex_gold">Duplex Gold - $720</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="duplex_platinum">Duplex Platinum - $855</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="duplex_diamond">Duplex Diamond - $945</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="triplex_gold">Triplex Gold - $1040</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="triplex_platinum">Triplex Platinum - $1235</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="triplex_gold">Triplex Diamond - $1365</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="triplex_gold">Fourplex Gold - $1360</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="triplex_platinum">Fourplex Platinum - $1615</option>
        <option class="multiflat" value="triplex_gold">Fourplex Diamond - $1785</option>
      </select>


    </td>
    <td class="centercolumntd">
      <label for="warrantytype"><u>Select Warranty Type</u></label><br>
      <input class="basewarranty" type="radio" id="Gold" name="warrantytype" value="400" required><label for="Gold">Gold - $400</label><br>
      <input class="basewarranty" type="radio" id="Platinum" name="warrantytype" value="475"><label for="Platinum">Platinum - $475</label><br>
      <input class="basewarranty" type="radio" id="Diamond" name="warrantytype" value="525"><label for="Diamond">Diamond - $525</label><br>
      <input class="basewarranty" type="radio" id="Sellers" name="warrantytype" value="Sellers"><label for="Sellers" value="0">Sellers Warranty - $0</label><br>
      <select form="input_form" name="multiyear" id="multiyear" value="Multi Year Warranties" class="selectboxes">
        <option class="multiyr" value="0" selected disabled hidden>Multi-Year Warranties</option>
        <option class="multiyr" value="760" id="2yr_Gold">2yr. Gold Warranty - $760</option>
        <option class="multiyr" value="1120" id="3yr_Gold">3yr. Gold Warranty - $1120</option>
        <option class="multiyr" value="903" id="2yr_Platinum">2yr. Platinum Warranty - $903</option>
        <option class="multiyr" value="1330" id="3yr_Platinum">3yr. Platinum Warranty - $1330</option>
        <option class="multiyr" value="998" id="2yr_Diamond">2yr. Diamond Warranty - $998</option>
        <option class="multiyr" value="1470" id="3yr_Diamond">3yr. Diamond Warranty - $1470</option>
      </select>
      <select form="input_form" name="newconstruction" id="newconstruction" value="New Construction Warranties" class="selectboxes">
        <option class="newconst" value="" selected disabled hidden>New Construction Warranties</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="400" id="2yr_nc_gold">2yr. Gold New Constr. - $400</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="520" id "3yr_nc_gold">3yr. Gold New Constr. - $520</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="660" id="4yr_nc_gold">4yr. Gold New Cons"tr. - $660</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="475" id="2yr_nc_plat">2yr. Platinum New Constr. - $475</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="618" id="3yr_nc_plat">3yr. Platinum New Constr. - $618</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="784" id="4yr_nc_plat">4yr. Platinum New Constr. - $784</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="525" id="2yr_nc_diam">2yr. Diamond New Constr. - $525</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="683" id="3yr_nc_diam">3yr. Diamond New Constr. - $683</option>
        <option class="newconst" value="866" id="4yr_nc_diam">4yr. Diamond New Constr. - $866</option>
      </select><br>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<label for="warrantynotes"><u>Warranty Notes - Any instructions or information about the order or payment arrangements</u></label><br>
<input type="text" id="notes" name="warrantynotes"><br><br>

<label for="options"><u>Options</u></label><br>

<div class="warranty_option_container">
  <div class="wty_option_child">
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="greenplus" name="optiontype[]" value="70"><label for="greenplus">$70 Green Plus</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="termite" name="optiontype[]" value="75"><label for="termite">$75 Subterranean Termite Treatment</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="freezer" name="optiontype[]" value="50"><label for="freezer">$50 Freezer-Standalone</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="wetbar" name="optiontype[]" value="25"><label for="wetbar">$25 Wet Bar Refrigerator/2nd Fridge</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="poolspa" name="optiontype[]" value="150"><label for="poolspa">$150 Pool/Spa Combo</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="addpoolspa" name="optiontype[]" value="150"><label for="addpoolspa">$150 Additional Pool or Spa</label>
  </div>

  <div class="wty_option_child">
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="saltpool" name="optiontype[]" value="300"><label for="saltpool">$300 Salt Water Pool w/Spa Combo</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="wellpump" name="optiontype[]" value="100"><label for="wellpump">$100 Well Pump</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="septicpump" name="optiontype[]" value="75"><label for="septicpump">$75 Septic /Ejector Pump/Tank Pumping</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="waterline" name="optiontype[]" value="90"><label for="waterline">$90 External Water Line Repair</label><br>
    <input class="warrantyoptions" type="checkbox" id="waterlineandsewer" name="optiontype[]" value="195"><label for="waterlineandsewer">$195 External Water/Sewer Line Repair</label><br><br>
  </div>
</div><br>

<div class="warranty_option_container">
  <div class="wty_option_child" id="wty_option_child1">
    <h2>Warranty Total:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="wty_option_child" id="wty_option_child2">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your attempt .

Comment: Please see my updated version

Comment: thank you for the assistance.  Using your suggestions, I was able to get it to work... successfully, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

It was NOT trivial. Especially not after I noticed the jQuery

```js
const getCheckedValue = fld => {
  let val = $("option:checked",fld).text();
  if (val) val = val.split("- $")[1]
  return isNaN(val) ? 0 : +val;
}

$("#input_form").on("input",function(e) {
  const dtf = getCheckedValue("#duplex_triplex_fourplex");
  const multiyear = getCheckedValue("#multiyear");
  const newconstruction = getCheckedValue("#newconstruction");

  const $warrentyField = $("[name=warrantytype]:checked");
  const warrenty = $warrentyField.length>0 ? +$warrentyField.val() : 0;  

  const optiontypes = $("[name^=optiontype]:checked")
  .map(function() { return isNaN(this.value) ? 0 : +this.value })  
  .get();
  const optionType = optiontypes.length>0 ? optiontypes.reduce((a,b) => a+b) : 0;
  
//  console.log(dtf,warrenty,multiyear,newconstruction,optionType) 
  $("#total").text(dtf+warrenty+multiyear+newconstruction+optionType);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="input-form" name="textinput" id="input_form" method="POST">
  <table id="formtable">
  
      <td id="radiocell">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td class="centercolumntd">
              <label for="closingdate"><u>Closing Date</u></label><br>
              <input type="date" id="closingdate" name="closingdate" required><br><br>
              <label for="hometype"><u>Type of Home</u></label><br><br>
              <input type="radio" id="Single Family" name="hometype" value="singlefamily" required><label for="Single Family">Single Family</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home" name="hometype" value="towncondomobile"><label for="Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home">Townhome/Condo/Mobile Home</label><br>
              <select form="input_form" name="multitype" id="duplex_triplex_fourplex" value="Multi-Flat Warranty Options" class="selectboxes">
                <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>Duplex/Triplex/Fourplex</option>
                <option value="duplex_gold">Duplex Gold - $720</option>
                <option value="duplex_platinum">Duplex Platinum - $855</option>
                <option value="duplex_diamond">Duplex Diamond - $945</option>
                <option value="triplex_gold">Triplex Gold - $1040</option>
                <option value="triplex_platinum">Triplex Platinum - $1235</option>
                <option value="triplex_gold">Triplex Diamond - $1365</option>
                <option value="triplex_gold">Fourplex Gold - $1360</option>
                <option value="triplex_platinum">Fourplex Platinum - $1615</option>
                <option value="triplex_gold">Fourplex Diamond - $1785</option>
              </select>


            </td>
            <td class="centercolumntd">
              <label for="warrantytype"><u>Select Warranty Type</u></label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="warrantytype" value="400" required><label for="Gold">Gold - $400</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="Platinum" name="warrantytype" value="475"><label for="Platinum">Platinum - $475</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="Diamond" name="warrantytype" value="525"><label for="Diamond">Diamond - $525</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="Sellers" name="warrantytype" value="Sellers"><label for="Sellers" value="0">Sellers Warranty - $0</label><br>
              <select form="input_form" name="multiyear" id="multiyear" value="Multi Year Warranties" class="selectboxes">
                <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>Multi-Year Warranties</option>
                <option value="760" id="2yr_Gold">2yr. Gold Warranty - $760</option>
                <option value="1120" id="3yr_Gold">3yr. Gold Warranty - $1120</option>
                <option value="903" id="2yr_Platinum">2yr. Platinum Warranty - $903</option>
                <option value="1330" id="3yr_Platinum">3yr. Platinum Warranty - $1330</option>
                <option value="998" id="2yr_Diamond">2yr. Diamond Warranty - $998</option>
                <option value="1470" id="3yr_Diamond">3yr. Diamond Warranty - $1470</option>
              </select>
              <select form="input_form" name="newconstruction" id="newconstruction" value="New Construction Warranties" class="selectboxes">
                <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>New Construction Warranties</option>
                <option value="400" id="2yr_nc_gold">2yr. Gold New Constr. - $400</option>
                <option value="520" id "3yr_nc_gold">3yr. Gold New Constr. - $520</option>
                <option value="660" id="4yr_nc_gold">4yr. Gold New Cons"tr. - $660</option>
                <option value="475" id="2yr_nc_plat">2yr. Platinum New Constr. - $475</option>
                <option value="618" id="3yr_nc_plat">3yr. Platinum New Constr. - $618</option>
                <option value="784" id="4yr_nc_plat">4yr. Platinum New Constr. - $784</option>
                <option value="525" id="2yr_nc_diam">2yr. Diamond New Constr. - $525</option>
                <option value="683" id="3yr_nc_diam">3yr. Diamond New Constr. - $683</option>
                <option value="866" id="4yr_nc_diam">4yr. Diamond New Constr. - $866</option>
              </select><br>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <label for="warrantynotes"><u>Warranty Notes - Any instructions or information about the order or payment arrangements</u></label><br>
        <input type="text" id="notes" name="warrantynotes"><br><br>

        <label for="options"><u>Options</u></label><br>

        <div class="warranty_option_container">
          <div class="wty_option_child">
            <input type="checkbox" id="greenplus" name="optiontype[]" value="70"><label for="greenplus">$70 Green Plus</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="termite" name="optiontype[]" value="75"><label for="termite">$75 Subterranean Termite Treatment</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="freezer" name="optiontype[]" value="50"><label for="freezer">$50 Freezer-Standalone</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="wetbar" name="optiontype[]" value="25"><label for="wetbar">$25 Wet Bar Refrigerator/2nd Fridge</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="poolspa" name="optiontype[]" value="150"><label for="poolspa">$150 Pool/Spa Combo</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="addpoolspa" name="optiontype[]" value="150"><label for="addpoolspa">$150 Additional Pool or Spa</label>
          </div>

          <div class="wty_option_child">
            <input type="checkbox" id="saltpool" name="optiontype[]" value="300"><label for="saltpool">$300 Salt Water Pool w/Spa Combo</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="wellpump" name="optiontype[]" value="100"><label for="wellpump">$100 Well Pump</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="septicpump" name="optiontype[]" value="75"><label for="septicpump">$75 Septic /Ejector Pump/Tank Pumping</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="waterline" name="optiontype[]" value="90"><label for="waterline">$90 External Water Line Repair</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="waterlineandsewer" name="optiontype[]" value="195"><label for="waterlineandsewer">$195 External Water/Sewer Line Repair</label><br><br>
          </div>
        </div><br>

        <div class="warranty_option_container">
          <div class="wty_option_child" id="wty_option_child1">
            <h2>Warranty Total: <span id="total"></span></h2>
          </div>
          <div class="wty_option_child" id="wty_option_child2">
            <h2></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```